# How do you specify subplots to rqt_plot?

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I specify subplots to rqt_plot?

```
rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot /uav/0/pose/pose/position/x:y:z /uav/0/vel/vector/x:y:z
```

gives me six curves. I would like to have one plot for the pose and one for the velocity. How do I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61913/how-do-you-specify-subplots-to-rqt_plot?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Similar thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/59251/rqt_plot-not-plotting-data/).

Looks like accepting argument from commandline is a high demand? Or are people just working on tutorials that tell to do so?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-01**:
Well, I have not managed to create a subplot in the UI either. But of course you need to be able to start programs from the command line so you can make launch files for different types of setups. ROS is as I see it command line based and that is a very good thing.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-27**:
Just FYI, [tutorial is updated](http://answers.ros.org/question/59251/rqt_plot-not-plotting-data/) so that taking arguments from commandline is removed from there.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-27**:
It would be nice if the tutorial showed how to use sub plots also.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2014-08-08**:
I believe this answer is not answering the question. There is still no information given about how to create subplots.

**Comment by [superjax](https://answers.ros.org/users/20144/superjax/) on 2014-09-23**:
I agree, I end up writing big python scripts to automatically plot data because I don't know how to command rqt_plot to create subplots.